# How to ask Rubocop to check specific method/keyword usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I want to discourage the usage of `unscoped` in our codebase. Is there an existing linter in rubocop that allows me to specify keywords? If not, do I have to write a custom cop if I want to accomplish it?

Comment: `unscoped` is a method - not a keyword. Keywords are identifiers that have a specific significance to the parser such as `if, else, case, do, when`

Comment: After seeing [this issue](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/2939) I guess the answer is to write a custom cop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My peer helped me. Looks like we will need to write a custom cop.

```
module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module Hired
      class Unscoped < Cop
        MSG = "Avoid using `unscoped`."

        def_node_matcher :unscoped?, <<-END
          (send _ :unscoped)
        END

        def on_send(node)
          return unless unscoped?(node)
          add_offense(node, :expression, MSG % node.source)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Drop it in a folder, like say `lib/cops/` then add this to `.rubocop.yml`:

```
require:
- ./lib/cops/<whatever_you_called_the_file>.rb
```

see http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/NodePattern

Comment: Looks good! :-) Note that `MSG` is automagically passed to `#add_offense` if you omit the last argument.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't cover cases where safe navigation is used like `var&.unscoped`. You'll need to add a separate `on_csend(node)` to cover that and update the matcher to be:
`{ (send ... :unscoped) (csend ... :unscoped) }`